# How many different ways are there to get the second row in a SQL search?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I was looking for the second most highest record.

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
    `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `value` int(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `name`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, 'foo', '200'), (NULL, 'bar', '100'), (NULL, 'baz', '0'), (NULL, 'quux', '300');
```

The second highest value is `foo`. How many ways can you get this result?

The obvious example is:

```
SELECT name FROM my_table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

Can you think of other examples?

I was trying this one, but `LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery` is not supported.

```
SELECT name FROM my_table WHERE value IN (
    SELECT MIN(value) FROM my_table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Are you just curious, or is there a problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Just curious. It's just a thought problem we were talking through. If it were a real problem, I'd stick with `OFFSET`.

Comment: Do you want a MySQL only solution or a general (i.e. ANSI SQL) solution?

Comment: My guess: there are about six different ways.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'd prefer MySQL so I can quickly test, but I'm open to others for this thought experiment.

Comment: Five (two are more or less identical) and still counting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works for **exactly** the second highest:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table two
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM my_table one
        WHERE one.value  > two.value
                AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM my_table zero
                WHERE zero.value > one.value
                )
        )
LIMIT 1
        ;
```

This one emulates a window function rank() for platforms that don't have them. It can also be adapted for ranks <> 2 by altering one constant:

```
SELECT one.*
        -- , 1+COALESCE(agg.rnk,0) AS rnk
FROM my_table one
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT one.id , COUNT(*) AS rnk
        FROM my_table one
        JOIN my_table cnt ON cnt.value > one.value
        GROUP BY one.id
        ) agg ON agg.id = one.id
WHERE  agg.rnk=1 -- the aggregate starts counting at zero
        ;
```

Both solutions need functional self-joins (I don't know if mysql allows them, IIRC it only disallows them if the table is the target for updates or deletes)

The below one does not need window functions, but uses a recursive query to enumerate the rankings:

```
WITH RECURSIVE agg AS (
        SELECT one.id
        , one.value
        , 1 AS rnk
        FROM my_table one
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM my_table zero
                WHERE zero.value > one.value
                )
        UNION ALL
        SELECT two.id
        , two.value
        , agg.rnk+1 AS rnk
        FROM my_table two
        JOIN agg ON two.value < agg.value
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM my_table nx
                WHERE nx.value > two.value
                AND nx.value < agg.value
                )
        )
SELECT * FROM agg
WHERE rnk = 2
        ;
```

(the recursive query will not work in mysql, obviously)

Comment: I can't get any of them to work in MySQL (as you mention), but I appreciate the creativity of all three. Now, the real question: do you owe me three more to make six or does that include the others above as well?

Comment: Strange, the first two should work in mysql IMO. What is the problem, the self join, or some minor syntactic differences ? **2:** No allready at 2(others) + 3(mine); only need one more.

Answer (score 2):

Eduardo's solution in standard SQL

```
select *
from (
  select  id, 
          name, 
          value, 
          row_number() over (order by value) as rn
  from my_table t
) t
where rn = 1 -- can pick any row using this
```

This works on any modern DBMS except MySQL. This solution is usually faster than solutions using sub-selects. It also can easily return the 2nd, 3rd, ... row (again this is achievable with Eduardo's solution as well).

It can also be adjusted to count by groups (adding a `partition by`) so the "greatest-n-per-group" problem can be solved with the same pattern.

Here is a SQLFiddle to play around with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/286d0/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline initialization like this:

```
select * from (
  select  id, 
          name, 
          value, 
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
  from    my_table t, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
  order by value desc
) tb
where tb.rank = 2
```

Comment: I like it. Thanks. For more on MySQL User-Defined Variables see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name 
FROM my_table 
WHERE value < (SELECT max(value) FROM my_table)
ORDER BY value DESC 
LIMIT 1


SELECT name 
FROM my_table 
WHERE value = (
  SELECT min(r.value)
  FROM (
    SELECT name, value 
    FROM my_table 
    ORDER BY value DESC 
    LIMIT 2
  ) r
)
LIMIT 1
```